# C++ template class with argument copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I have a c++ generic class that looks like this:

```
template <class T, int N> class TwoDimArray{
    private:
        T tda_[N][N];
        int n_;
    public:
        TwoDimArray(T tda[][N]){
           ..
        }
        ~TwoDimArray(){
           ..
        }
        ..
}
```

How would I write a copy constructor that I will be able to call somehow like this:

```
int a1[][2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
TwoDimArray <int, 2> tdm1(a1);
TwoDimArray tdm1Copy (tmd1); // or whatever the correct form is
```

I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of typos in your code, but declaring a copy constructor is simple:

```
TwoDimArray(const TwoDimArray& rhs){/*implement it here*/}
```

The copy constructor is part of a template class, so you must specify the template type when copying

```
TwoDimArray<int, 2> tdm1Copy (tdm1); // specify <int,2> as the type
```

or use `auto`

```
auto tdm1Copy(tdm2);
```

Full working example below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, int N> class TwoDimArray {
private:
    T tda_[N][N];
    int n_;
public:
    TwoDimArray(T tda[][N]) {
        // implement
    }
    ~TwoDimArray() {
        // implement
    }
    TwoDimArray(const TwoDimArray& rhs) // don't really need this
    {
        // implement
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a1[][2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    TwoDimArray <int, 2> tdm1(a1);
    TwoDimArray<int, 2> tdm1Copy (tdm1); // specify <int,2> as the type
}
```

Unless you are doing this for a homework or learning purposes, just use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` to "simulate" a 2-D array.

---

**Additional remark:** Since your class contains an array (and not a pointer, they are not the same), you don't need a copy constructor. The default copy constructor does it for you, i.e. copies the array element by element. So, just get rid of the copy constructor altogether and let the compiler generate a default one.

Comment: Could you help with the implementation for these exact two variables too?
I did it like this:
'TwoDimArray(const TwoDimArray& rhs) : tda_(rhs.tda_), n_(rhs.n_){
 }'
but I'm getting ": cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays"

Sorry about the typos, I tried to refactor.. Yes, 'homework purposes'..

Comment: You cannot asign an array to another. Since your class contains an array (and not a pointer, they are not the same), you don't need a copy ctor. the default copy ctor does it for you, i.e. copies the array element by element. So, just get rid of the copy ctor altogether so you let the compiler generate a default one.